# VBA String Limit

Tags: vba, string, limit, ado

I've been working in Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) in Microstation V8i SS2, and I'm getting an Overflow error for my String value.

It seems there is a limit in VBA for String values. The limit seems to be 255 characters. Reading up on it, a lot of sources says it can support up to 2 billion characters. This is not true?

What happens is, I'm using ADO to interact with the database, so I'm building my own SQL INSERT statement inside the VBA. The INSERT statement gets long, like 300+ characters, depending on the 'Comments' column that accepts a multi-line text value.

Anybody have a solution? Should I write my own COM-Addin from a .NET point of view, that gets referenced in the VBA?

[image: MsgBox Len(ssql)]

[image: Visual Basic Break]

[image: Error handler result]

Comment: Are you sure the error is a string variable error?  Most commonly, this error occurs when you put too big a number in an Integer.  Can we see the code that's erroring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VBA strings can be more than 255 chars.

A possible culprit is how the column is declared in your table.... Is the `Comments` column declared as `varchar(255)`?

From the help file:

- A variable-length string can contain up to approximately 2 billion (2^31) characters.
- A fixed-length string can contain 1 to approximately 64K (2^16) characters.

[Ref](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/a1d8ee65-75e6-4a29-9670-6e233c398642/).

Comment: actually, [fixed length strings hold up to 65,526 characters which is less than 2^16 (*65,536*)](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=46toCUvklIQC&pg=PA3&dq=if+you+attempt+to+create+one+with+more+than+65,526&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4VvvUoKhCpSthQfMloDgDw&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=if%20you%20attempt%20to%20create%20one%20with%20more%20than%2065%2C526&f=false).

Comment: 10 less. Thanks for the clarification. Also, link doesn't work for me. BTW I did say approximately. It's implicit that some overhead would be required.