# Excel-VBA string manipulation issue

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy some 8-digit numbers to use in a SQL search.

The SQL query gave me errors and after some debugging I found that the string doesn't contain all the data. It seems that after 25 or so numbers my for loop stops entering data as if the string is full.

Thanks for the help...

```
Lots = ""
For iRow = 2 To 500
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("Filtered Data").Cells(iRow, 2)) Then Exit For
    Lots = Lots & ",'" & Sheets("Filtered Data").Cells(iRow, 2).value & "'"
Next iRow

Lots = "(" & Mid(Lots, 2, Len(Lots) - 1) & ")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should post your data raising the errors

as for while you can consider the following code to build-up the string exploiting [Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264098(v=office.15).aspx) function

```
Dim Lots As String

With Worksheets("Filtered Data") '<--| change "Filtered Data" with your actual worksheet name
    With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) '<-- consider its column "B" cells from row 2 down to last non empty one
        Lots = "('" & Join(Application.Transpose(.Value), "','") & "')" '<-- build up the string
    End With
End With
```

this assumes that all non empty cells in column "B" are contiguous (i.e. non blank cells in between non blank ones), but it can be easily modified should this not be the case

Comment: i tried you code, but the issue still remains. The Lots string only collects the first 26 numbers and doesn't ads the finel " ') ". I'm sorry but i cannot upload all the code or the data i'm working on.

Comment: you could upload the first 27 numbers only, in order to help people helping you

Comment: Sorry, can't upload my data(IP issues). But it doesn't matter what numbers there are, just try it on a 27 8-digit numbers.

Comment: I tried with 28 numbers: `12345678`, `12345679`,...,`12345705` and it correctly returned:`('12345678','12345679','12345680','12345681','12345682','12345683','12345684','12345685','12345686','12345687','12345688','12345689','12345690','12345691','12345692','12345693','12345694','12345695','12345696','12345697','12345698','12345699','12345700','12345701','12345702','12345703','12345704','12345705')`

Comment: are your data actually in contiguous cells from row 2 downwards?

Comment: yes. i have tried to place the Lots string in a cell and it seems OK now. but now i'm having issues passing it to my SQL Function but without any success.

Comment: Now it looks like a SQL related syntax problem: you may want to open a new post with your current SQL command problem. As for this post problem If my answer resolved it please mark it as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. Presumably you have an empty cell in the column which is making it exit the loop....

Comment: Can you add this as a comment to the question rather than as an answer?

Comment: apparently not, if you don't have a 50 reputation

Comment: The data has no empty cells. i'm using the same code here in another macro and its working fine there, but in my new macro it seems that the string has limits.

Comment: Assuming Lots is declared as a string, it doesn't have a limit that will be affecting your data.

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927764/vba-string-limit

So it must be an issue somewhere else. Without having all of the code, and the file you are using it is very hard to help

Comment: @BarryAibinder I tried it on 150 8 digit numbers and it worked fine. There must be more to your code or data than meets the eye.